# ASP.NET project building with this error: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll

Tags: visual-studio-code

The only package that references Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll is here: [image]

These errors are showing up in the console intermittently when building/running - but only in Visual Studio Code for Mac, not in Visual Studio for Mac or Rider:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
[01:07:28 INF] Application Starting Up
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

I can run the project just fine from Visual Studio for Mac or Rider, but I get this error when using Visual Studio Code for Mac. Stumped. I've even uninstalled .NET Core runtimes and reinstalled them (latest versions of .NET Core 2 and 3).

Any ideas?